# Jquery change table cell value if other cell contains word

Tags: php, jquery

I have a basic table and need to change a word if one of the other cells in that row contains a word.

```
<table>
    <tr class="veh-row">
        <td class="vehicle_desc">RED CAR</td>
        <td>4000 miles</td>
        <td class="veh-trans">Manual</td>
        <td>Petrol</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="veh-row">
        <td class="vehicle_desc">RED CAR</td>
        <td>4000 miles</td>
        <td class="veh-trans">Manual</td>
        <td>Petrol</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="veh-row">
        <td class="vehicle_desc">RED CAR AUTO</td>
        <td>4000 miles</td>
        <td class="veh-trans">Manual</td>
        <td>Petrol</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I need if `td.vehicle_desc` contains the word `AUTO` then `Manual` will change to `Automatic` in `td.veh-trans`. How can I do this and only effect that row and not all other rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :contains

```
$('td.vehicle_desc:contains(AUTO)').siblings('.veh-trans').text('Automatic')
```